# Rock, Paper, Scissors made with switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to develop my first game with Js, the issue is that my scores and round variables are not getting summed up, when I console log them they don't show like this: playerScore = 2, computerScore = 1, round = 2, here's my code.

```
    // Computer random selection 
function computerPlay() {
    //Game options to play with 
    let options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    //Random number generator
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    //Select random option from array
    let computerSelection = options[randomNumber];
    // return value so the game can be played
    return computerSelection;
}

let computerSelection = computerPlay();

let playerSelection = computerPlay();

//Round
let round = 1;

//Add round
function addRound () {
    round += 1;
}

//Scores
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// Start round, define winner, loser or tie game 
function playRound (playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    //concatenate strings to match cases 
    switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
        // Tie case
        case 'RockRock':
        case 'PaperPaper':
        case 'ScissorsScissors':
            playerScore += 0;
            computerScore += 0;
            return 'Tie Game!'; 
        // Player score
        case 'RockScissors':
        case 'PaperRock':
        case 'ScissorsPaper':
            playerScore += 1;
            return `${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}, You Won!`;
        // Computer score    
        case 'ScissorsRock':
        case 'RockPaper':
        case 'PaperScissors':
            computerScore += 1;
            return `${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}, Computer Won :(`;
    }
    addRound();
}
    
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

console.log(playerScore, computerScore);
```

This is the output of the console:

```
    Scissors beats Paper, You Won!
    1 0

    Tie Game!
    0 0
```

Comment: Where are you calling `playRound()` for the second game? FYI `addRound()` will never be called because you `return` from all your cases

Comment: Instead of using return should I only use break?  and just print the `${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}, You Won!` into the HTML file?

Comment: I have in mind creating another function called game and entering right there the playRound function

Comment: I'm not asking about what you might have in the future, I'm asking how exactly you ran it twice to produce the output above

Comment: I produced that output by entering node main.js into my console twice

Comment: Every time you run `node main.js`, that's starting from scratch with scores initialised to `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `return` in `swich-case`, which will not execute the code below the  `return` statement. And `addRound()` function is below the `return` statements. By moving it on upper side will do the work

```js
const computerPlay = () => {
  const options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  const computerSelection = options[randomNumber];
  return computerSelection;
}

let round = 0;

let addRound = () => round += 1;

let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function playRound() {
  let computerSelection = computerPlay();
  let playerSelection = computerPlay();

  addRound();

  switch (playerSelection + computerSelection) {
    case 'RockRock':
    case 'PaperPaper':
    case 'ScissorsScissors':
      playerScore = 0;
      computerScore = 0;
      return 'Tie Game!';
    case 'RockScissors':
    case 'PaperRock':
    case 'ScissorsPaper':
      playerScore += 1;
      return `${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}, You Won!`;
    case 'ScissorsRock':
    case 'RockPaper':
    case 'PaperScissors':
      computerScore += 1;
      return `${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}, Computer Won :(`;
  }
}

console.log(playRound());
console.log(playerScore, computerScore, round);

console.log(playRound());
console.log(playerScore, computerScore, round);
```